# Pinia store in Typescript Vue component gives error "Property 'testStore' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance'...."

Tags: javascript, typescript, pinia

I've a `<script setup>` block in which I import my `testStore` but whenever I want to use `this.testStore.name` somewhere in my vue file vetur gives me this error:

```
Property 'testStore' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<{ [x: string & `on${string}`]: ((...args: any[]) => any) | undefined; } | { [x: string & `on${string}`]: undefined; }, {}, {}, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 10 more ..., {}>'.
  Property 'testStore' does not exist on type '{ $: ComponentInternalInstance; $data: {}; $props: { [x: string & `on${string}`]: ((...args: any[]) => any) | undefined; } | { [x: string & `on${string}`]: undefined; }; ... 10 more ...; $watch(source: string | Function, cb: Function, options?: WatchOptions<...> | undefined): WatchStopHandle; } & { ...; } & ShallowU...'.Vetur(2339)
```

Since I'm a typescript n00b I don't really know how to fix this and the Pinia docs don't really seem to help me out on this matter(I can only find how I can make a shim for custom properties but nothing about having to define my stores or something).

this is my pinia store file(testStore.ts)

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

const state = () => ({
  name: 'This is my store'
});

const actions = {};

const getters = {
};
export const useTestStore = defineStore('testStore', {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
});
```

This is my .vue file

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { useTestStore } from '@/stores/testStore';
const testStore = useTestStore();
</script>
<template>
  {{ testStore.name }}
</template>
<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'testStore',
  mounted () {
    console.log(this.testStore.name)
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should be

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
  import { useTestStore } from '@/stores/testStore';
  
  const testStore = useTestStore();

  console.log(testStore); // testStore should displayed
</script>

<template>
  {{ testStore.name }}
</template>
```

Notice:

```
<script setup lang="ts"></script>
```

and

```
<script lang="ts">
  export default defineComponent({});
</script>
```

Both are used to define components, use one of them, don't use both.

Some Vue doc that you might need:

https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html

https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/options-api.html

Comment: Uhm. I don't see the difference between my code and yours to be honest?

Comment: In your .vue file. You should remove second script tag and then work with your store in first script tag

Comment: Oh right, I'm mixing composition and options API which seems to screw it up? Just out of convention: Which would you prefer?

Comment: In my opinion, i would love to use composition API. It makes your code easier to organize

Comment: Thanks! I'll take it into consideration. I'm so used to the options API that I never thought of not being able to mix them properly (Since non-TS doesn't care haha)